# Track campaigns with Google Analytics without query string parameters?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there a supported way in Google Analytics to track a campaign without having to use query string parameters.

In Analytics you can [tag a link to your site](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55518) with query string parameters such as `utm_campaign` and `utm_medium` which carry information about the campaign so that they can be tracked.

Google actually has an [online tool](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578&hl=en) to help in the creation of such links.

For instance if StackOverflow was advertising on Experts Exchange they may have a link like this :

http://www.stackoverflow.com/?utm_source=expertexchange&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=a-better-expert-exchange

For many reasons I don't want these clumsy looking parameters appearing in my URLS :

- I want to encourage twittering, and long links discourage this
- I dont want people bookmarking them with campaign IDs in
- I want people to see a clean URL
- I dont want search engines indexing these links.
- I want full control about what parameters are sent to google analytics - and not leave it up to my partners to mess up the URLs they access my site with

I looked a while ago to try to find a way wherein you could set these parameters. [Google has a page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html) which at first glance looks like the solution, but actually isn't. That page describes how you can change the names of the query string parameters to something else - for instance to use `src` instead of `utm_source` you would run :

```
 pageTracker._setCampSourceKey("src");
```

I really cannot seem to figure out why they don't make it easy to actually explicitly set the value of the `utm_source` key - and not just set up an alternative parameter name for it.

I remember a while back finding someone who had a kind of nasty hack, but I cant even seem to find that now. I seem to recall though that whoever it was took a copy of the analytics code and essentially branched it off and hacked at it. This is not a good solution for me!

is there an officially supported way of doing this at all, without some kind of nasty redirects.

In a nutshell I want to do something like this (ASP.NET MVC site). Give a partnet a link to my site with a URL like this :

```
 http://www.example.com/?cid=2dae88a8-66b1-475d-8a35-2978bd1a158c
```

In the controller for my MVC page I would find out what campaign this GUID related to, and set the model state. Note: this gives me the advantage that i can change the campaign parameters without having to reissue the URL.

In the page itself I would then do this:

```
var campaignMedium = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignMedium %>;
var campaignSource = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignSource %>;
var campaignName = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignName %>;

pageTracker._setCampaignData({
    utm_source: campaignSource,
    utm_medium: campaignMedium,
    utm_campaignName: campaignName
});
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

**IMPORTANT: This _setCampaignData method DOES NOT ACTUALLY EXIST. This is just 'pseudo code' for what I'd ideally like to be able to do.**

Has anyone successfully managed to do anything like this?

Comment: adding bounty cos i'd really like to see any updates on this question - but not enough time (or optimism) to research it myself. fingers crossed though! thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [solution using push(['_set', 'campaignParams',...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082585/5118762) seems only to work for the [legacy library ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns?hl=de).

Using analytics.js you need to specify the campaign param separately. E.g.

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'TheCampaignName...');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'someCampaignSource');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'email');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignName

Comment: Wow ten years since I asked this!

Comment: Likewise, for the new `GA4` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76517545/1747491).

Answer (score 32):

### _set campaignParams

Your theoretical "_setCampaignData" finally exists, in the form of `["_set","campaignParams",...]`

If you have a way to programmatically inject the values you'd like to set (for example, set by a cookie on a redirect, or on the server side and printed onto the page), you can use the `_set` API to hard-code the campaign params that you'd like to set.

The format for that is just:

```
_gaq.push(['_set', 'campaignParams', 
'utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN&utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=MEDIUM']);
```

So, using your original example:

```
 var campaignMedium = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignMedium %>;
 var campaignSource = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignSource %>;
 var campaignName = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignName %>;
 _gaq.push(['_set', 'campaignParams', 
'utm_campaign=' + campaignName +  '&utm_source=' + campaignSource +'&utm_medium=' + campaignMedium]);
```

### Update 2017

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624890/172322) details how to accomplish this with the newer Google Analytics library, analytics.js/Universal Analytics.

Comment: This sounds over complicated to me.
Just compute the internal ID and update location.hash in JS and get GA to process it

Comment: It is pretty complicated :), but apparently the `location.hash` approach creates problems with the back button and, potentially, the cookies being re-written.

Comment: I just added a much simpler approach :)

Comment: location.search.match(/utm_/) or location.hash.match(/utm_/) ?

Comment: Note that that `_gaq.push(['_set', 'campaignParams', ...])` should be placed before the `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])`

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution does not work for me.  Perhaps that is why it still goes undocumented, but I have referenced numerous examples and the _gaq.push(['_set', 'campaignParams', ...]); method simply does not work.  I know my analytics work because if I manually add the query string it works fine.

Comment: This seems only be recommended for the old ga.js. For analytics.js see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934119/track-campaigns-with-google-analytics-without-query-string-parameters#35624890)

Answer (score 11):

Török Gábor gave me an idea.

```
// ...
var campaignMedium = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignMedium %>;
var campaignSource = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignSource %>;
var campaignName = <%= ViewData.Model.CampaignName %>;

// save the old hash
var oldHash = document.location.hash;

// add campaign data to the hash
document.location.hash = 'utm_source=' + escape(campaignSource) + ...;
pageTracker._setAllowAnchor(true);
pageTracker._trackPageview();
// restore the old hash:
document.location.hash = oldHash;
```

This way, you could create the campaign data in the backend, and then, pass it to the hash dynamically, and then restore it without user even noticing it. I.e. the campaign tracking is 100% independent of the real URL.

Comment: This seems to mess up the browser history, at least in FF 3.5. Pressing back goes to the hashed version, back again, un-hashed version, back a third time goes to the previous page. Any tricks to keep the hash out of the history?

Comment: I'd also be worried about the page flickering while that fires off a post-back.

Comment: I don't think you need to store and restore the hash value.
But I believe this is the way to go:
process the private ID, express the campaign parameters into the hash through JS, and track pageview once done

Answer (score 7):

There is a function [`_setAllowAnchor`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor) in the Trackin API that allows you to specify the tags in the anchor text instead of as query parameters.

```
pageTracker._setAllowAnchor(true);
```

So you can use `http://www.stackoverflow.com/#utm_source=expertexchange` and GA will understand it. This way you can avoid the SEO problem.

For the Twitter problem, I suggest you the method described in post [Tracking Twitter and Shorten URLs in Google Analytics](http://blog.avangate.com/twitter-analytics-love/).

Answer (score 7):

I posted this to the Google help forum.

Google Please Read!!! Great enhancement opportunity!!!  This is causing a lot of users not to be able to use the Advertising parameters.  Allow the Advertising parameters to be read from the URL used on trackPageview(url).

In any case, without this capability, I had to use a work-around.  Rather than appending the parameters to the URL.  I temporarily appended them to the URL as a bookmark.  Then I removed them after the trackPageview call.  By adding them as a bookmark, the page is no reloaded.  See the following example.

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(param);
var orighash = document.location.hash;
if (orighash == "") {
    orighash = "none";  // this is done to prevent page scrolling
}
document.location.hash = 'utm_source='+source+'&utm_campaign='+campaign+'&utm_medium='+medium+'&utm_content='+content;
pageTracker._setAllowAnchor(true);
pageTracker._trackPageview();
document.location.hash = orighash
```

Comment: This is a common workaround I've seen.  (You may want to edit your post and fix the code fromatting)

Answer (score 7):

Below is an updated way to do this using the Google Analytics Universal method of Event tracking rather than GA Standard Event tracking.

The entire UTM string can be extracted from the queryString (when there) or pulled from the Google cookie (__utmz) and then passed into Google Analytics using the below code.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'queryString', 'getQueryString', googleString );
```

Then, upon execution of whatever trigger you want to create (I use a function named "widgetTracker"), you can execute the GA event tracker.

Here's the entire code:

```
/* JavaScript Document */
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-xx', 'xx.xxx');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

 var googleString;  
 var stringArray = [];  
 var queryStringObject = makeQueryStringObject();   
 var QUOT = "'";    
 var EQ = '=';  
 var AMP = '&';         

 for  ( var v in queryStringObject ) {  
    var str =  v + EQ + queryStringObject[v] ;  
    stringArray.push(str);   
    googleString = stringArray.join(AMP);
} 

         function makeQueryStringObject()   {       
            var obj = [];       
            var pageURL = window.location.href;         
            var URLArray = pageURL.split('?');      
            if( URLArray[1] )       {           
                var argsArray = URLArray[1].split('&');             
                var l = argsArray.length;           
                for( i=0; i<l; i++ )            {               
                    var individualArg = argsArray[i].split('=');                
                    if(individualArg[1] && individualArg[1].indexOf('#') > -1)              {               
                        var dropHashArray = individualArg[1].split('#');                    
                        individualArg[1] = dropHashArray[0];                
                    }               
                    obj[ individualArg[0] ] = individualArg[1];     
                    console.log("value of queryStringObject: " + individualArg[0] + " :: " + obj[   individualArg[0] ]);

                }       
            } else { /* from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14984832/1013405 */         
                ga1 = parseGACookie();  
                if(ga1['utmcsr']) {             
                    var utm_source = ga1['utmcsr'];                     
                }           
                    if(ga1['utmccn']) {             
                        var utm_campaign = ga1['utmccn'];                   
                    }           if(ga1['utmcmd']) {             
                        var utm_medium = ga1['utmcmd'];                 
                        }           
                        if(ga1['utmctr']) {             
                            var utm_term = ga1['utmctr'];                           
                        }           
                        if(ga1['utmcct']) {             
                            var utm_content = ga1['utmcct'];                
                        }       
                    }   
                        var googleString2 = "utm_campaign=" + utm_campaign + '&' + "utm_medium=" + utm_medium + '&' + "utm_term=" + utm_term + '&' + "utm_content=" + utm_content;  
                    return obj;     
                } 

                function parseGACookie()  {     
                var values = {};     
                var cookie = readCookie("__utmz");     
                if (cookie) {         
                    var z = cookie.split('.');         
                    if (z.length >= 4) {             
                        var y = z[4].split('|');            
                         for (i=0; i<y.length; i++) {                 
                            var pair = y[i].split("=");                 
                            values[pair[0]] = pair[1];             
                         }         
                        }     
                    }     
                    return values; 
                }  


                function readCookie(name) {     
                    var nameEQ = name + "=";     
                    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');     
                    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {        
                     var c = ca[i];        
                      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);         
                      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);     
                    }     
                    return null; 
                }  
                function widgetTracker() {  
                /* event tracking order of elements: send (required), event (required), Category, Action, Label, Value */ 
                    if (googleString) { 
                    ga('send', 'event', 'queryString', 'getQueryString', googleString ); 
                    } else { 
                     ga('send', 'event', 'queryString2', 'getQueryString2', googleString2 ); 
                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I didn’t test it, but try to add those params to the `.trackPageview()` method, i.e.:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("?utm_source=...")
```

Anyways, You have to pass those parameters some how. And this means, you’ll allways have long URL-s with some kind of campaign crap in them. It won’t prevent bookmarking the wrong URL-s, search engines indexing them, etc.

If you want to maintain control of those parameters, setup separate URL-s for partners, that redirects to the tagged target URL:

```
http://example.com/campaigns/1 -> http://example.com/?utm_source=...
```

Comment: Beware, remove the forward slash from the argument because it modifies the real path of the actual query.

Comment: i still have yet to test it, but apparently this doesn't work. its a real shame in my opinion. see http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=56716b97618cd64d&hl=en

Comment: It won't work, trackPageview value isn't read to lookup for campaign parameters, it is just what's logged as the current page

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Google Analytics API to customize the call to _trackPageview in your example.

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("/inbound/" + campaignSource + "/" + campaignMedium );
```

All of the inbound links will then show up in Google Analytics under the /inbound/ "pseudo directory" with a separate "directory" for Campaign Source and Campaign Medium.

Answer (score 2):

The new(er) universal analytics allows you to specify these params - see the documentation here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

Look for the "Campaign Source" section for an example of setting what would be the utm_source param.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the update train for `Google Analytics 4`, see [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11259997).

- We're using `Google Tag Manager` to install GA4, so we used the instructions to override fields in the `GA4 Configuration tag`.
- There's also instructions for overriding the `gtag.js` library in code:

  ```
    gtag('set', {
        'campaign_id': 'google_1234',
        'campaign_name': 'Summer_fun',
        'campaign_source': 'google',
        'campaign_medium': 'cpc',
        'campaign_term': 'summer+travel',
        'campaign_content': 'logolink',
    });
  ```