# How to capture if a visitor is from a google adwords click

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-ads-api, web-analytics

When a user signs up on my site I want to be able to store whether or not they came to my site via an Adwords campaign.

I know google uses javascript to track conversions based on a cookie that is created on the users machine. Is there a way I can check this cookie so I can store the source against the user account?

Comment: See this question: [Detect if user is coming from a Google Adwords ad](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/20299/51926) on Webmasters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're correct--you can read this data from the cookies.

To configure the tracking:

1. connect your adwords and GA
   accounts:
2. in your AdWords account, go to My
   Account > Account Preferences, click
   the "edit" link next to Tracking
   then select the box that says
   "Destination URL Auto-tagging".
   Click "Save Changes";
3. still from your AdWords account,
   click the Analytics tab and choose
   Analytics Settings > Profile
   Settings > Edit Profile Information;
   check "Apply Cost Data", then click
   Save Changes

So how can you tell if it's working? And where does GA store the data?

Grab an initial __utm.gif request and look at the Referer. Appended to the URL is a new parameter "**gclid**." This is the keyword-specific parameter (unique to your account). It's this parameter that distinguishes your visitors as AdWord-originating (i.e., "google(cpc)") from "google(organic)" Here's one i just grabbed and anonymized (scrambled the numbers/letters):

Referer: http://www.adomainname.com/?**gclid**=CKr61p31yKACFZlg4wodjj3gbA

You'll see this identical string in two other places in the same tracking pixel request:

(i) as the value for the GIF Request Parameter "**utmp**" which is the page request for the current page, and, most importantly;

(ii) as the value for the GIF Requests Parameter "**utmcc**"--the container for the cookies. The specific cookie that holds the adwords data is **__utmz**, which is actually the container for all referral data.  Here's an anonymized example i just grabbed more or less at random (i.e., i just did search in Google using a query comprised of obvious Adwords and then clicked one of the paid links in my search results, then just pulled the Request Header):

> utmcc=__utma%3D755416178.1576730350.1269876846.1269143846.1269143846.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D219726107.1269143846.1.1.utmgclid%3CKr61p31yKACFZlg4wodjj3gbA%7Cutmccn%3D(not%2520set)%7Cutmcmd%3D(not%2520set)%7Cutmctr%3Dhomes%2520for%2520sale%3B
>   HTTP/1.1

Comment: where from we set the 3rd setting.I can't find any Analytics tab in adwords.

Comment: This seems to be out-of-date.

Comment: Is it a MUST to install GA?
I just want to detect the visitor coming from Adwords click or not in my server.

Answer (score 18):

You could add an additional url parameter to the url you gave at google adwords, and check for it on your site and store in a session variable or cookie.

At registration of a user account check for this session or cookie you have created and act accordingly..

Comment: I already have adword campaings set up and would really like to be able to access the cookie.

Comment: +1 I used a variation of this technique successfully, prior to seeing it here, and can confirm it is effective. I wasn't permitted to setup Analytics on a WordPress landing page so had to come up with a workaround. I added a parameter to the destination URLs of my AdWords adverts and appended some JavaScript code to the bottom of the WordPress page to extract the parameter from the URL (location.search) and append it to the URL of a link in the page via document.getElementById('link-id').href.

Answer (score 10):

I know this already has an accepted answer but it's very out of date. The updated way can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en

C+P'd:

> In order for Analytics to display details about your AdWords keywords
>   and costs, you must do one of the following:
>
> Enable auto-tagging. This is the recommended approach and ensures that
>   you get the most detailed AdWords data. Manually tag all your keyword
>   final URLs with tracking variables. You should only do this in the
>   special cases outlined below.
>
> How auto-tagging works Auto-tagging automatically imports AdWords data
>   into Analytics. Combining AdWords data with the rich post-click
>   information provided by Analytics allows you to see what happened on
>   your site after people clicked on your ads.
>
> When you enable auto-tagging, a parameter called gclid is added to
>   your landing page URL when a user clicks over to your site from an ad.
>   For example, if your site is www.mysite.com, when a user clicks on
>   your ad it appears in the address bar as:
>
> www.mysite.com/?gclid=123xyz
>
> Enable auto-tagging To enable/disable auto-tagging:
>
> Sign in to your AdWords account. Click the gear icon, and select
>   Account settings. Make sure you're on the Preferences tab, and click
>   Edit in the Tracking section. Select (enable) or clear (disable) the
>   Auto-tagging checkbox. Click Save changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could always provide an adwords-specific landing page. That way you have a lot freedom to do whatever you want with the incoming adwords user...

Comment: Yes I have thought of this but i would like to be able to read the cookie(s) so im not tied to a single adwords campaign.