# activating fancybox when visited from google ads

Tags: jquery, fancybox, google-ads-api

Hi I would like to activate fancybox on my website every time someone comes to my site by clicking on google ads. Fancybox is usualy triggered by clicking on a link.
Is it posible and what would be the best way to do that?
Many thanks, Dino.

Comment: You could check via cookie if the referrer site is Google ads or not... then launch fancybox accordingly. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485971/1055987 for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your AdWords account is linked to Google Analytics, then you could check for the presence of the `gclid` parameter.

Alternatively, you could just add a query parameter to the destination URL, then pick it up in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the technicalities behind Google ads and what information you get server/browser-wise to indicate that someone has visited your site through Google ads; however, using jQuery and the following code would load fancybox when the page loads.

```
$(function(){
    $('#my-element').fancybox();
});
```