# Google Analytics Widget Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, forms

I have a form that is generated on a customer's website (lets say customer.com) with javascript that a user fills out and it sends to my site (app.com). I would like to be able to provide information to the customer such as how effective their AdWords campaign was and what search engines users used to end up filling out the form.

I have started looking at the multiple [domain linking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#%5Fgat.GA%5FTracker%5F.%5Flink) option but I am not sure this is the right way.

Is there a way to query what search engine and key words they used and pass this along with the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question but [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688657/how-do-i-extract-google-analytics-campaign-data-from-their-cookie-with-javascript) details how to extract data from the _utmz cookie (which by default contains the most recent referrer & keyword is present).