# Retrite Source, Medium etc. from __utmz GA using jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to be able to retrite the campaign, source and medium that google analytics records at the same time as the page loads.. is this possible? if so im guessing looking up the values from __utmz using jquery?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also, by 'retrite', do you mean 'rewrite'? Or maybe retrieve?

Comment: i have the same problem. check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934119/track-campaigns-with-google-analytics-without-query-string-parameters

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html