# Set utm_source and utm_term for trackpageView in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to record a page view using analytics for a certain url with values of utm_source and utm_term which are sent from serverside.
I thought this would do the job:

```
<script>

var trackPageViewUrl = window.location.pathname + 
                       "?utm_source={utm_source}&utm_term={utm_term}";
trackPageViewUrl = trackPageViewUrl.replace("{utm_source}", '<%= ServerSideVar1 %>')
                                    .replace("{utm_term}", '<%= ServerSideVar2 %>');

// Tracking code
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', trackPageViewUrl]);    

(function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
</script>
```

No the problem is that I see pageviews from the url window.location.pathname but there are no values for utm_source and utm_term on which I could filter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sadly, GA does not support this behavior, though it would be great. There are some hacks out there. See this question for some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/q/934119/172322

Comment: Thank you very much. Post it as answer I'll accept it :). I think it will work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, GA does not support this behavior, though it would be great. There are some hacks out there. See this question for some alternatives (including one that I proposed, the current accepted answer):

### [Track campaigns with Google Analytics without query string parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/934119/172322)