# Campaign data not being passed

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm testing Google Analytics Campaign tracking. I have the following JavaScript code on my local page triggered by an onclick event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackCampGoogle() {
try {
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']); 
_gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', 'ga_campaign']);    // name
_gaq.push(['_setCampMediumKey', 'ga_medium']);    // medium
_gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', 'ga_source']);    // source
_gaq.push(['_setCampTermKey', 'ga_term']);        // term/keyword
_gaq.push(['_setCampContentKey', 'ga_content']);  // content
_gaq.push(['_setCampNOKey', 'ga_nooverride']);    // don't override
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','CampTrackerGoogle']);
setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
}catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

When I click the link in Chrome with the GA Debugger on, the tracking beacon fires, but doesn't show campaign data being passed:

```
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : (direct)
Campaign Medium          : (none);
Campaign Name            : (direct)
```

This is, uh, frustrating. What am I missing? We need the campaign data to be passed via JavaScript rather than in the URL.

Comment: Can you provide a sample URL? You're changing the URL parameters that GA is looking for, so you need to make sure you're changing them in the actual URL.

Comment: I thought I could "force" a campaign hit the same way you can use trackpageview to force a page hit, but you cant, for some stupid reason. So if you want to do campaign tracking using javascript instead of long ugly URLs your're screwed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934119/track-campaigns-with-google-analytics-without-query-string-parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `_set` to do this, before the `_trackPageview` and `_setDomainName`.

```
_gaq.push(['_set', 'campaignParams', 'utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN&utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=MEDIUM']);
```

Comment: LOL is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Not yet, but I suspect it will be soon. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ALh3C/

Comment: I suspect it won't soon if it isn't yet - it's been possible since Nov 2010 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4082585/16940

Comment: @Simon_Weaver No, if you'll note the edit history, I only added information about that feature very recently.

Comment: is there an update for this for the new tracking code? ga.js - ga()